# pass arguments through a subprocess and terminate the subprocess when closing the main program in Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, subprocess, parameter-passing

I have two Python files, file 1 and file 2 that does two separate things. I want to run them together. I am using VS2017

The pseudo code for file 1 is:

```
Class A:
   foo1():
    .
    .
   foo2();
    if variable<30;
        #do this
    else;
      process = subprocess.Popen('py file2.py' ,shell=True,stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)

    #rest of the code for foo2()

if __name__ == "__main__":   
  A.foo2();
```

I also wanted to pass a variable to the second file. I am looking into something like

```
variable = input("enter variable)
cmd = ['py file2.py', variable]
subprocess.Popen(cmd ,shell=True,stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

I am getting an error saying:

> '"py subproleap.py"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

And Even if I do pass the variable how do I get the file2.py to read it?

Any help would be appreciated. I am a beginner in python.

EDIT1:
Why I use subprocess is that I want the file2.py to run in the background,once the condition is met, while the main process runs in the side.

Comment: Consider running in separate thread

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true) may answer your question (you are using the `shell=True` param)

But wouldn't it be easier to import `file2` as a module in `file1`? (if you're not already familiar with importing, you can refer to [this guide](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html))

Comment: Linking to another question is not a good answer; unfortunately, that cancels out the +1 I would give for the `import` suggestion.